# What's a good snack or meal to have before weightlifting?

Tags: weightlifting, food, eating-habits, pre-workout

When I haven't lifted weights in a while, I often get nauseous during my workout, usually causing me to not finish it. I read that eating properly before going to the gym may help avoid this. Has anyone found this to be helpful?

Which snacks or meals have helped you and how long before exercising did you consume them?

Comment: This is going to be highly individual, what works for one person may not work for another. I would encourage you to read the help and intro sections to help you form good questions for the site.

Comment: Agreed with @JohnP Some people (like me) don't eat at all before gym because i just feel tired if i do and have much more energy if i don't, for some, it is the other way around. Just try what feels good for you (eggs, cheese, some carbs maybe).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.muscleforlife.com/pre-workout-nutrition/ has some good information on this.

When I am not trying to lose weight, I've been eating 1 cup almond milk, 1 frozen banana, 1 scoop whey blended together.

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely depends on your body type and what you're going for, i.e. fat loss, building muscle, etc.

**Keep in mind...No one can tell you what is right FOR YOU.**

However...

My favorite source is http://www.muscleandstrength.com/. They have a lot of great articles on exercises and nutrition.

For my individual routine, often times I will have 1 scoop of whey protein in milk as a shake about 45 mins - 1 hour before I work out and maybe a banana for the energy and electrolytes boost and a glass of water but I am trying to maintain muscle and concentrate on high density workouts.

If you don't want to spend the time researching, you may consider consulting with a nutritionist or sitting down for a session or two with a personal trainer at a local gym.